# Why does Julia 1.0 failed to write to STDOUT but Julia 0.6 works

Tags: julia

```
function main()
    (k, a, b, a1, b1) = (BigInt(2), BigInt(4), BigInt(1), BigInt(12), BigInt(4))
    while true
        (p, q, k) = (k*k, BigInt(2)*k+BigInt(1), k+BigInt(1))
        (a, b, a1, b1) = (a1, b1, p*a+q*a1, p*b+q*b1)
        (d,d1) = ( div(a,b),div(a1,b1) )
        while d == d1
            write(STDOUT,string(d))
            (a,a1) = ( BigInt(10) * (a % b), BigInt(10) * (a1 % b1) )
            (d,d1) = ( div(a,b),div(a1,b1) )
        end
    end
end

main()
```

When I compile it it gives me the error message

```
$ julia pi_2.jl 
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: STDOUT not defined
```

It worked perfectly in julia 0.6 and produced all the digits of Pi

```
$ julia06 pi_2.jl 
3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816...
```

Comment: Try to remove all unnecessary code in your example. Just `write(STDOUT, "hello")` would be sufficient to demonstrate your problem in this case.

Answer (score 10):

`STDOUT` is renamed to `stdout` in Julia 1.0.

I recommend you to use Julia 0.7 instead of Julia 1.0 if you are porting from Julia 0.6.

Julia 0.7 and Julia 1.0 have the same functionality, but Julia 0.7 most of the time will print a warning where Julia 1.0 errors in places when there is a breaking change from Julia 0.6.

Comment: Thanks. I have install julia 0.7 as julia07 on my Mac. I thought I could skip it and go straight to 1.0 but it turn out to be painful.